# Content gets larger when displayed in an iFrame?

Tags: css, iframe, styling

I have a web page that fits perfectly in most mobile phones, but when i embed that page in an iframe to be able to display its content on another page, i can only see about 75 % of the page width on mobile phones (iPhone, Galaxys, iPad); the experience is that the content on the embeded page gets larger in an iFrame. Has anyone else stumbled upon this issue and know how to resolve it?

The iframe has the following styling:

```
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

[image: Page not in an iframe]
[image: page embeded in an iFrame]

Comment: perhaps try adding `frameborder="0"`
I dont realy understand your question... please provide more code and perhaps a screenshot of the problem....

Comment: I added some screenshots. Basicaly, the exact same page becomes "bigger" when embeded within an iframe.

Comment: try adding `-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);` and `-moz-transform-scale(0.5);` instead of these numbers you can try diferent values... i added these nubers for the purpose of demonstration

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: That seems to work, but feels like a work-around?

Comment: why would it be a workarround? its a legitimate tag that scales elements...
P.S can i post it as an answer to your question and will you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-webkit-transform:scale(0.5); -moz-transform-scale(0.5);` to the css style of your `<iframe>` and that should work...

Instead of these numbers (which I wrote for demonstration purpose) I recomend you try some other values that you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) for better result...